# How do I get the last inserted key in Python (>3.7) dict without iterating through the whole list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know that Python dict's `keys()` since 3.7 are ordered by insertion order. I also know that I can get the first inserted key in O(1) time by doing `next(dict.keys())`

What I want to know is, is it possible to get the last inserted key in O(1)?
Currently, the only way I know of is to do `list(dict.keys())[-1]` but this takes O(n) time and space.

By last inserted key, I mean:

```
d = {}
d['a'] = ...
d['b'] = ...
d['a'] = ...
The last inserted key is 'b' as it's the last element in d.keys()
```

Comment: What's the context here - why do you want to know the last inserted key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dicts support reverse iteration:

```
next(reversed(d))
```

---

Note that due to how the dict implementation works, this is O(1) for a dict where no deletions have occurred, but it may take longer than O(1) if items have been deleted from the dict. If items have been deleted, the iterator may have to traverse a bunch of dummy entries to find the last real entry. (Finding the *first* item may also take longer than O(1) in such a case.)

If you want to both find the last element and remove it, use `d.popitem()`, as Tim Peters suggested. `popitem` is optimized for this. Starting with a dict where no deletions have occurred, removing all elements from the dict with `del d[next(reversed(d))]` or `del d[next(iter(d))]` is O(N^2), while removing all elements with `d.popitem()` is O(N).

In more complex cases, you may want to consider using `collections.OrderedDict`. `collections.OrderedDict` uses a linked list-based ordering implementation with a few advantages, one of those advantages being that finding the first or last element is always O(1) regardless of what deletions have occurred.

Comment: Still O(n) - not what OP asked for, right?

Comment: @LarrytheLlama: Are you under the impression that this builds a list and then picks the last element? It doesn't. It uses the same mechanism that a regular dict iterator uses, just in reverse.

Answer (score 3):

@[user2357112 supports Monica]'s `next(reversed(d))` does the trick. I'll add that, when I want the most recently added key, I *usually* want to remove it from the dict too. In that case, a simple `d.popitem()` does the trick.

### CAUTIONS

> I also know that I can get the first inserted key in O(1) time by doing next(dict.keys())

That doesn't work. If you try, you'll get

```
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not an iterator
```

However, e.g., `next(iter(d))` will work.

But it's not necessarily `O(1)`. It is for the `OrderedDict` library implementation, but not for the built-in dicts. The problem is that if, e.g., you delete "the first" key over & over & over ... again, that leaves an increasing number of "holes" at the start of the data structure, and finding the first non-hole has to skip over all of those one at a time.

So, in a loop, repeatedly deleting the first and then accessing the new first can take time quadratic in the number of loop iterations. You probably won't notice unless the dict has at least about 10 thousand elements, though.

Comment: You mean `popitem`, right?

Comment: Thanks - I did mean that, and changed the reply accordingly.

Comment: I see you finished writing your efficiency warning before I did. I wish there was a more efficient way to handle this for regular dicts, but it'd probably have to expose too many implementation details (constraining the implementation in the process), and `collections.OrderedDict` or manual order management are both options.

Comment: If anyone cared enough to fight for it ;-) , it should be easy to change the dict implementation to keep track of the index of the currently "first" non-hole entry. When you deleted "the first", the implementation of `__del__` would need to search for the next non-hole, but entries before that would never need to be skipped over again. I think it might be "a fight", though, because it would slightly slow (in the amortized sense) adding and deleting dict keys, to keep that index up to date.